# Program won't exit for first for loop and I have no idea why

Tags: c

The program is supposed to find amicable pairs. The first input tells you how many numbers will follow and the program is supposed to figure out which of those numbers are amicable pairs. I don't know if the program is actually able to do that though, since I can't even get past the first `for` loop, which is literally just putting the elements that need to be checked into an array.

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int numberOfNumbers, num;
    scanf("%d", &numberOfNumbers);

    int numbers[numberOfNumbers];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfNumbers; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &num);
        numbers[i] = num;
    }
```

I expect the program to move onto the calculation part of the code (which I didn't include) and produce some output, whether it's right or not, but instead after I've entered the last number it just acts as if it wants another input. At that point I could enter every digit of Graham's number and it still won't exit.

Comment: I can't see anything that would make the loop infinite. It seems more likely that the code that comes after the loop is behaving improperly, or an error is happening that you didn't notice.

Comment: Put a `printf` right after the loop to verify that.

Comment: what happens if you put  getchar(); after the loop?

Comment: Hallo! You've omitted some code that you think is irrelevant but is this the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the problem? I notice there are no `#include` files and a missing closing `}` brace. Is this the *actual code* that misbehaves?

Comment: looks fine to me

Comment: We need *all* of your code, even your calculation. Please include it.

Comment: Always check the returned value of `scanf`. `numberOfNumbers` may be left uninitialized.

Comment: "after I've entered the last number it just acts as if it wants another input" -- So the infinite loop is in your calculation, not during the input, no?

Comment: Wholly unrelated to the apparent loop — It doesn't appear that you are using command lines arguments, so you should probably use the `int main(void)` form to define the main function.

Answer (score 1):

The first step of debugging a problem is validating you have the problem you're considering fixing.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfNumbers; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &num);
    numbers[i] = num;
}
```

Is the loop that you are thinking of fixing.

```
printf("entering loop\n");
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfNumbers; i++) {
    printf("i is %d, numberOfNumbers is %d\n", i, numberOfNumbers);
    scanf("%d", &num);
    numbers[i] = num;
}
printf("loop finished\n");
```

is the code you would would need to completely validate that your guess about the loop is correct (or wrong).

I hope this helps, even if it is not a direct answer.  Your code looks good, but could be wrong based on a lot of items (including the user input).

Comment: Another crucial step would be checking that `scanf()` actually returns `1` and not `0` or EOF.